# Catch the exception or trown the business exception directly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Data.

In the Service Layer, which is better, try to insert the record and catch the "Already Inserted" Exception by the unique key and than translate it into the business exception or use the repository to find the record and than throw the business exception directly?

Comment: It is always better to abstract the detailed reason from clients. It is better to throw custom exception with appropriate message after you catch some DB exception

Answer (score 1):

Database PK is the best approach to maintain uniqueness constraint, if you try approach of querying and checking for PK then you could get in race condition where it will pass the unique check but fails in insert, so any way SQL exception thrown should be handled.
So it is better to handle via Exception and translate to meaning full business error.